# Mac showing special characters in menu items

Tags: macos, font, menu-bar

My Mac Pro is showing special characters "??????" in all my menu items. See image below:

[image]

I am not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to clear the font cache is to boot into Safe Mode. Restart your Mac while holding down `Shift`.

Once the restart has completed, then restart normally.

Alternatively, you can run the following Terminal command, and then Restart:

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
```

You will need to supply an admin password.